# Indexing of column in table was interrupt, table doesn't answer

Tags: mysql, indexing

MySQL, HeidiSQL
I have table with big amount of data. I started query (bad idea)

```
alter table mytable add index somecolumn;
```

But execution was interrupted (HeidiSQL was crushed) and after restart I can't get data from this table.
How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Restore the backup you made before altering the table?

Comment: it's very big statistics table and there is no backups for it